# Angular language service in VSCode does not work because it is not an Angular project ('@angular/core/core.d.ts' could not be found)

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, tsconfig, angular11, angular-language-service

Somehow the Angular (v11.0.4) language service in VSCode does not work anymore. I get the following error message.:

```
[Info  - 17:52:04] Angular language server process ID: 147359
[Info  - 17:52:04] Using typescript/lib/tsserverlibrary v4.0.5 from ~/.vscode-oss/extensions/angular.ng-template-0.1100.2/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserverlibrary.js
[Info  - 17:52:04] Using @angular/language-service v11.0.3 from ~/.vscode-oss/extensions/angular.ng-template-0.1100.2/server/node_modules/@angular/language-service/bundles/language-service.js
[Info  - 17:52:04] Log file: ~/.config/Code - OSS/logs/20210112T090839/exthost2/Angular.ng-template/nglangsvc.log
[Info  - 17:52:06] Disabling language service for ~/Workspace/NG_PROJECT/tsconfig.json because it is not an Angular project ('@angular/core/core.d.ts' could not be found). If you believe you are seeing this message in error, please reinstall the packages in your package.json.
[Error - 17:52:06] Failed to find project for ~/Workspace/NG_PROJECT/projects/apps/app1/src/app/*.html
[Error - 17:52:53] No config file for ~/Workspace/NG_PROJECT/projects/apps/app1/src/app/*.html
[Error - 17:52:54] No config file for ~/Workspace/NG_PROJECT/projects/apps/app1/src/app/*.html
```

I already tried:

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

but it does not solve the problem.

What can I do to solve that issue?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The last thing I remember is I've updated vscode.

Answer (score 49):

Update to @Begandroide's answer. "Ivy" is no longer considered experimental, and so the `Enable-experimental-ivy-prompt` is no longer an option. With the latest major version (12.x...) of the **Angular Language Service** VSCode extension, you must enable the `Use legacy View Engine language service` option.

[image]

Comment: This was required for an older project, `ngcc` would fail. Thanks!

Comment: It work for me, good!

Comment: I updated my project to Angular 13. Its not possible to choose the Legacy view engine for Angular 13 and above. Now with ivy the Angular language service is failing. Its really frustrating to work without extension. 

Comment: Update: I tried it in a new project in Angular 13. So it seems some issue with the config itself. Will keep you posted .....

Comment: @JEWELJACOB, any luck? Experiencing the same issues

Comment: Not yet, I was not able to find the root cause.

Comment: For me (in an Angular 12 project) I had to unmark  the "User legacy View Engine..." to make it work.

Answer (score 37):

I'm facing the same issue and I resolved it by going to the marketplace of VS Code, then go to `Angular language service` extension and click on settings, then extension settings [image]

Finally, you must disable experimental-ivy and reload window (VS Code)
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Begandroide,
Is there any way to enable this feature without any errors?

Comment: Glad i could help, really i don't know if we can enable this feature without errors, i believe we could create a issue on github to the extension of market place (Angular language service).

Comment: finally. Thanks